# Using dynamic popups in leaflet

Tags: r, leaflet, r-leaflet

I'm making a leaflet map with popups.  The popups give information of the ID of the polygon being selected. The problem I have is that the name of the field use for ID can change, so the way I was originally doing doesn't work anymore.

Here is a reproducible example:

```
## preparing the RE:
library(maps); library(sf); library(leaflet); library(htmltools)
w = st_as_sf(map('world', plot = FALSE, fill = TRUE))
```

What I use to do is prepare a html string to display:

```
text <- paste0("<b>ID %s</b>")
```

Then call the leaflet and populating the popups with `sprintf` and `htmlEscape`

```
leaflet(data=w) %>% addTiles() %>% 
  addPolygons(
    popup = ~sprintf(
      text,
      htmlEscape(ID)
    )
  )
```

This works great :
[image]

However, the field isn't always called `ID`, but the name is known and in a r object (here called `vari`):

```
colnames(w) <- c("geometry", "country")
vari <- "country"

text <- paste0("<b>", vari, " %s</b>")
leaflet(data=w) %>% addTiles() %>% 
  addPolygons(
    popup = ~sprintf(
      text,
      htmlEscape(vari)
    )
  )
```

This doesn't work:
[image]

I've tried using `as.name` so it would be considered as a symbol but it doesn't work:

```
vari <- as.name("country")

text <- paste0("<b>", vari, " %s</b>")
leaflet(data=w) %>% addTiles() %>% 
  addPolygons(
    popup = ~sprintf(
      text,
      htmlEscape(vari)
    )
  )
Error in sprintf(text, htmlEscape(vari)) : 
  invalid type of argument[1]: 'symbol'
```

Any idea how to fix that?  BTW, my HTML is more complex than in my example (uses more variables, however, all other variable names are fixed, only the ID field change).

Comment: You mean like some countries have their name as a field called "ID", and others have it as a field called "Country" or whatever else? Maybe it's a silly question, but is there a way you can standardize your data first so you don't have to deal with this?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear, it's the field that could be called different things, like "ID", "country", "pays", etc.  Standardizing could work I guess, I'll do that if I don't find a better solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you're after, but it sounds like you want to be able to simply populate any popup with the data from a column that doesn't necessarily have the name `ID`, but is simply an identifier agnostic of title? So in this case `country`? I fear this is an ugly cheat, but given your data structure contains a data.frame where the coords are actually a list structure, i simply test the dataframe columns for class, whichever is a character, use that as the index and directly call

```
leaflet(data=w) %>% addTiles() %>% 
  addPolygons(
    popup = ~sprintf('<b>ID %s</b>', w[[names(which(mapply(is.character, w)))]])
  )
```

[image]

Comment: This works.  it is indeed kind of an ugly cheat ;), but it fixes my problem so thanks!

Comment: sweet. If you want to expand on scenarios we could clean it up haha